# Netscaler and blue/green deployment

Tags: load-balancing, blue-green-deployment, netscaler

I would like to apply blue/green deployment by using Netscaler as a load balancer. I’ve been told that by putting a status file on a server, the load balancer knows that the particular server should not be in production. For example, you have server blue (online) and server green (offline). Server green has a file, for example offline.html. Due to this file the load balancer knows that no traffic should be allocated to server green. You deploy a new version of the app on server green. You remove the offline.html file on server green and add the file on server blue. You do this to put server green live and server blue offline.

Does someone has experience with this and does someone knows the official name of this “status file”?

Thank you in advance!

Try to read the Citrix documentation but I’m not sure if I was seeking at the right place.